# PhantomJS PHP exec() command not working in the browser

Tags: php, permissions, phantomjs

I am using phantom JS to get the raw HTML of a webpage.
It is working when I use the terminal but not in the browser.
Please refer the photos:

```
exec("/Users/kaustubh/Desktop/phantomjs /Users/kaustubh/Desktop/loadspeed.js "."http://www.google.com ",$output);
var_dump($output);
```

I had already referred many similar question and the conclusion is something **related to the permission.**

What do you think about this error ?
The code of **loadspeed.js** is :

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),system = require('system'),t, address;
 if (system.args.length === 1) {
console.log('Usage: loadspeed.js <some URL>');
phantom.exit(1);
}else{
address=system.args[1];
var websiteAddress = address;
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 
Safari/537.36';
page.viewportSize = { width: 1920, height: 1080 };

 page.clipRect = { top: 0, left: 0, width: 1920, height: 1080 }; page.open(websiteAddress, function (status) {
    setTimeout(function(){
    page.render('github.png');
    console.log(returnChunksArray(page.content,6000));
    phantom.exit();
 }, 5000); // 5 sec should be enough
});
}
function returnChunksArray(str, chunkSize) {
 var arr = [];
 while(str !== '') {
    arr.push(str.slice(0, chunkSize));
    str = str.slice(chunkSize);
 }
 return arr;
}
```

When the browser is concerned: the browser does not even wait for the **exec()** function.I even tried shell_exec() but no success.
[image]

The permission for hpantomjs is read and write :[image]

But in the terminal ,it loads as expected.
Thanks

Comment: Can you even run a simplest `shell_exec` with command like `ls` via PHP?

Comment: I think i have fixed it..it's the permission problem. Just change the phatomjs directory and  loadspeed.js to the server's directory.Thanks for your response